# Subscribe youtube js

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube

I would like to know how to detect if a person is entered in my youtube channel. If it is I release the reading, otherwise it needs to sign up.

I tried with the youtube button, but it does not work, never returns me value when I click.

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>

<script>
  function onYtEvent(payload) {
    if (payload.eventType == 'subscribe') {
      alert('Yes')
      // Add code to handle subscribe event.
    } else if (payload.eventType == 'unsubscribe') {
      alert('no')
      // Add code to handle unsubscribe event.
    }
    if (window.console) { // for debugging only
      window.console.log('YT event: ', payload);
    }
  }
</script>

<div class="g-ytsubscribe" data-channelid="UCMuP3q3YcWziAcqZA" data-layout="default" data-count="default" data-onytevent="onYtEvent"></div>
```

I would like to know to enter the page, or if I am not registered in the channel. Similar to Social locker.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Youtube has deprecated that feature.

> Note: The Subscribe Button's subscribe and unsubscribe events have
>   been deprecated. Similarly, the data-ytonevent attribute, which could
>   previously be added to the widget element to specify a listener for
>   event notifications, has also been deprecated.

Reference - https://developers.google.com/youtube/subscribe/reference